# Encrypt password for a Powershell script to be used by other customers

Tags: powershell

I've been searching all around the internet for a really safe solution but still nothing worth. My script expects a connection to O365 but I actually run it on my machine so I can almost store the password in a file and then decrypt it easily with my account. The problem begins when I want to - for example - make a zip with all the files and give it to a customer without the fear to get my password stolen.

The only solution I have found is to use an exact key to encrypt but, how could I "hide" it? I mean, I first encrypt using 
`[Byte[]] $key = (1..16)` 
then I go into the script and use:

```
$File = “path\Password.pwd"
[Byte[]] $key = (1..16)
Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key
```

but if the key I used to encrypt is written in the script, they should be able also to decrypt and we go back to the main problem. Is there any solution for this problem?
Thanks in advance, hope I won't get downvoted because I really couldn't find anything.

^
Update: I edit my request because I made a few researches and I assumed that the best way to encrypt is using the default Windows Apis. Now my request is if possible to run a script in a server with different users. Maybe the user could make a "run as administrator" that would let him run it and decrypt the password without any problem... I mean the big problem is I need it working on a server for multiple users who are not all administrators. Thanks.

Comment: There's inherently no safe solution to this. If your connection is protected by a password, and you want to give your customers direct access to that connection, then one way or another they'll need the password. You can put layers of obfuscation over it, but they'll always be able to get it one way or another, because it's necessary for things to work. Give your customers their own account with their own password instead (if they don't already have one) and share the files to that account. (I don't know what mechanism O365 has for this, but it must have some.)

Comment: short answer: no.
maybe you can create a limited account for them so they can manage what they need to manage using that account.

Comment: The powershell steroids plugin offers auto obfuscation and can also let you compile the script. All this can be reverse engineered, of course, but it makes it more difficult for the layman.

Comment: Agreed this is not possible. I think you need to look at another solution. This really sounds like you are trying to pass files (zip) from one user to another. There are several professional tools for things like this. Sharefile from Citrix is a easy one to use. You could also setup FTP server which there is alot of free software for things like that.

Comment: Thans for your answers first, I made an update to specify in a better way the situation.